# undefined local variable or method `acts_as_voteable' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Disclaimer: I'm a Ruby on Rails newbie. Tried Googling and searching StackOverflow without success.

I am creating my first Ruby on Rails app and would like to take advantage of the "thumbs_up" plugin which is similar to vote_fu and acts_as_voteable and works under Rails 3.
https://github.com/brady8/thumbs_up

I have followed the installation instructions on the page above and when I run "gem list" I see the thumbs_up plugin is installed.

I have attempted to add the "acts_as_voteable" mixin to a model which looks like this:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :title,       :presence => true
  validates :description, :presence => true

  acts_as_voteable
end
```

When I try to browse my app I receive the following error:

undefined local variable or method `acts_as_voteable' for #

The stacktrace does not look very useful to me:

> activerecord (3.0.0)
>   lib/active_record/base.rb:1016:in
>   `method_missing' app/models/foo.rb:7
>   activesupport (3.0.0)
>   lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:454:in`
>   load' activesupport (3.0.0)
>   lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:454:in
>   `load_file' activesupport (3.0.0)
>   lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in`
>   new_constants_in' activesupport
>   (3.0.0)
>   lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:453:in
>   `load_file' activesupport (3.0.0)
>   lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:340:in`
>   require_or_load' activesupport
>   (3.0.0)
>   lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:491:in
>   `load_missing_constant' activesupport
>   (3.0.0)
>   lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in`
>   const_missing' activesupport (3.0.0)
>   lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in
>   `each' activesupport (3.0.0)
>   lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in`
>   const_missing' activesupport (3.0.0)
>   lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:503:in
>   `load_missing_constant' activesupport
>   (3.0.0)
>   lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in`
>   const_missing' activesupport (3.0.0)
>   lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in
>   `each' activesupport (3.0.0)
>   lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in`
>   const_missing'
>   app/controllers/foos_controller.rb:5:in
>   `index'

Any ideas? I can't seem to make any progress on resolving this.

Thank you,
-Rob

Comment: Did you add this to your Gemfile and run "bundle install" from the command line?

Comment: Yes I did add "gem 'thumbs_up'" to my Gemfile and ran "bundle install".

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an initializer file

```
# config/initializer/thumbs_up.rb
require 'thumbs_up'
```

Or you could just require it from your model

```
# app/models/foo.rb
require 'thumbs_up'
```

Comment: This looks like it has worked. I will have to do some additional work in my view before I can confirm. Thanks monocle!